# Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions, post-ban

When I am posting my question I am getting the following error:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.

What can I do?

Comment: Stack Overflow account: http://stackoverflow.com/users/386431/wasim

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the problem is not simply related to your poor English, which can still be excused.

However, you have put no effort into asking your questions. I have read the first 3 and all of them are vague, and I am truly surprised they haven't been closed. I would suggest you take some time to read [Jon Skeet's guide to writing a perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Here's what you need to do, take a few days and read other's questions, watch how the community responds to those questions, and what they respond to negatively. Write your question in notepad first and rewrite until you feel that it meets the site criteria, and then post your question.

Also once ready, email team@stackoverflow.com to have you IP unbanned and allowed to post again. They could potentially ask you for a sample question to determine if it is truly valuable to unblock the IP. However, emailing them right now won't help, since your questions still meet the criteria for throttling.

Comment: This site does not have an adequate license to complete the requested action. Please contact the administrator.

I am getting this

Comment: @Wasim, did you get that license errror on http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx ? That would be odd. It's surely working now.

Comment: My account has been banned from asking questions again for the 4th time ... Stack need to do something about this ... its irritating

Comment: @YatinK: Did you read the answer? Or the question this is a duplicate of?

Comment: @Diago Thanks for the article

Comment: Please also help me... I also have a question ban, but not for a day but since a whole month. How to remove that?? Here's my profile link: stackoverflow.com/users/11363434/abhay-salvi?tab=profile Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 5):

This happens when an IP has a history of asking very poorly-rated questions, which yields [a permanent ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72180/clarify-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account-error/76167#comment-174366) of that IP address.

This is a permanent ban. It not only blocks your account, but also the IP address you were using. To prevent bypassing [the filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294), its exact details are not public. It is partly based on downvotes, and downvotes on deleted questions are also taken into account. (An account with a high public reputation might very well have many deleted questions, including [auto-deleted old low-score questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year), all of which are only visible to moderators.)

Comment: But I want to ask questions so what should I do now if someone is intentionally rating me down so what can i do for that.
Please help me if there is any solution

Comment: @Wasim One person mass downvoting you couldn't cause it, those get filtered out and probably wouldn't be enough anyway. Your account doesn't seem like it's posted a lot of bad questions; I can't see the complete history from your IP though, so it's hard to tell. I'm not sure what people can do to get off the blacklist, you probably need to wait for an SO mod to read this

Comment: Is there any method so that i can change my Ip address I am working on Windows Xp SP 2

Comment: But my english is poor and they are voting me down bcoz of my english i know If you look at my profile carefully one guy has also marked star on one of my question

Comment: Whom should I contact to activate my account

Comment: @Wasim: People may be voting you down based on your English, I don't know.  But a quick glance through your questions and answers show that you format your questions pretty poorly.  Other users continually have to edit your questions to make them readable. If you get your account back, try to improve that.  See the [formatting FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: @Wasim you can try and contact team@stackoverflow.com directly

Answer (score 5):

I got mine blocked from asking new questions on meta. I have asked 3, one of them got -15, one a small minus and the other a small plus.

Hardly a history of asking poorly-rated questions, plus on meta a negative rating does not necessarily indicate a poor question so perhaps that rule should not apply here? Especially on such few questions.

No chance of asking good questions now.

And no point in e-mailing as nobody replies.

Comment: Interesting point. I'll ask a question about this for you. EDIT: done, see [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76728/should-mso-use-the-poor-quality-questions-algorithm)

Comment: Yeah - Meta questions should be exempt from the mechanism. This can't stand.

Comment: @Pekka [Already discussed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67023/should-the-automated-ban-on-questions-used-on-so-apply-to-meta-as-well). I foresee some downvotes in my near future for this.

Comment: @Popular Remember that deleted questions are also taken into account - I can't say for how much impact this has, but it's something to think about. Since this has been going on for a while, and judging from the presence of emails being sent, I'm sure this isn't undetected.

Comment: Deleted my new question because it's a dupe of the one @Grace linked.

Comment: Each one of your questions has been discussed here before.  While we would like you to contribute in determining the overall direction of stack overflow, we would appreciate it if you would consider participating in existing discussions by searching on those topics you are interested in.

Comment: One of my questions had been deleted therefore did not come in the search, one was somewhat different if not slightly similar from the other proposal as well as not being obviously searchable. (With regard to my AnythingGoes.overflow I was actually originally thinking of offtopic.stackoverflow.com as an area for off-topic discussion but not the same as Yahoo! question exactly, because I felt it would attract mainly software-development discussion, but more stuff like discussed at thedailywtf.com). I any case I did what I was asked which was to e-mail team@stackoverflow.com and got no reply.

Comment: my account is blocked but don't know why, i asked 3 questions and only 1 got some answers. is it my fault if no one can answer my questions. and this rating system really sucks, Stackover team must do something regarding this. this is not possible for anyone to create new account again and again.