# Doing something about all the 0% accept rate users

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accept-rate

I have a suggestion for combating the 0% accept rate some users have, and continue to ask crappy questions.

Perhaps if they get to 10 questions with 0% accept rate (using the existing metric), could we hit them with a *please accept an answer on a previous question to ask your new question.*

I know SO now have the *asking questions advice* page if they have a low rep, but I was wondering if *forcing* them to accept one would help - maybe they just don't know how to accept, and if they were forced to accept one, then they would know how to from then on in.

I know SO has always been about freedom of asking questions, but I think after having asked 10 questions you need to give something back (by awarding rep, at least). It may clear up some noise at least.

Comment: Declined as [accept rate is no longer shown with on the usercard for a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/140951) (you'll never know what their accept rate is now).

Comment: @Mike it still exists behind the scenes, just not showing up anywhere. (Same like flag weight)

Comment: I guess I was saying that the information required to calculate the accept rate is available by viewing the users question history. Flags are not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is already a system in place to deal with people who issue a lot of *bad* questions (as determined by downvotes). They are [prevented from asking any more until they contribute](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56817/2509) to the site in a positive manner.

Acceptance rates are displayed, so you can make your own policy. My opinion is that no one is bound to accept anything, and you are *not* owed an acceptance.

Comment: You can ask questions with 0 reputation, thus down votes don't stop you from asking but simply from gaining any reputation.

Comment: @Chacha: There is now a system in place that *locks users out* if they ask too many bad questions. I'll find you a link... http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68616/2509 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63432/sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account and especially the link I added to the answer.

Comment: What about the good faith responders for those who have to suffer through the first "bad questions period"? :: Also, +1 for "you are not _owed_ an acceptance".  Good reminder.