# Criteria prohibiting asking further question on Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, superuser, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63432/sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account)
>   [SO Is not accepting questions from my account anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68616/so-is-not-accepting-questions-from-my-account-anymore)

I was going to ask another question on superuser.com but instead of the question form,
I was informed by the message

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting
>   questions from this account.

I don't know why this happened. I wasn't informed before that I'm doing something wrong
or break some rules of this forum.

What can I do to find out my mistakes and correct them?
Will I be able to ask new questions soon or has my interaction with superuser.com definitely ended?

Comment: And I assume that downvotes, closed posts and deleted posts are considered to be warnings?

Comment: I have four closed posts because I asked on the wrong place. I thought that members chosen better place and it's not so big fault. I was new to stackexchange, I'm getting better. I'm asking special question on special sites for them now. I can't see any downvotes.
This question is not a duplicate. I'm asking for the rules that I have to follow and which rules I broke and how to correct my faults.

Comment: I've got same issue on stackoverflow, getting that they're no longer accept questions and I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: What is this forum thing you are talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on Super User, 8 out of your 13 total questions have been deleted.  5 of them were closed, 4 migrated to other sites in the Stack Exchange, and 1 closed as off-topic.  Another question of yours was downvoted two times and was also closed.  So the system is seeing a pattern here...9 out of 13 questions closed is 69% off-topic.

Your questions seem to be somewhat low-quality and you have not answered any questions, so the system may believe that you are a serial question asker...

Comment: Read my comment to Will's answer. There is explained why this happened. Now the questions are deleted so it's impossible to view them. I asked for deleting them because I hoped that this will help. Unfortunately I won't be able to look at them.

Answer (score 1):

xralf, you aren't suspended that I can see.  You might be sharing an IP with someone who was binned. Same for @Niklas, although he needs to review his answers and think about the ones that were deleted and why.  He, also, isn't suspended or banned currently.

Comment: Did you check xralf's questions? Are many of them downvoted and deleted?

Comment: @GraceNote: I can't on SuperUser, but his account doesn't have 1 rep, which it does when it is under suspension.

Comment: Ah, right, this is on Super User. Should try to rally up some of them SU folk to take a gander, then.

Comment: OK, I will ask this on superuser meta and delete it here. Or should I rather accept? Thank you

Comment: @xralf: Nah, you asked it in the right place.

Comment: Are there some higher moderators for all stackexchange? After I asked on superuser one user closed another my question that was quite good (tagged readability which is related to software, note that I can't create such a tag). Other two questions should be asked on new "Drupal questions" site (I dind't know about it). My question about printer (related to software and hardware) was deleted. And last closed question was duplicate (I haven't noticed it). That is quite cruel and is not fair. My questions aren't so bad. Users were answering them and gave me good answers.

Comment: @xralf: You can find out everything you need to know about how to be productive on any site on the StackExchange network by reading the Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ) for the site (it is linked at the top of each page), and reading questions and answers for awhile to get a feel for what are considered good and bad questions to ask.

Comment: Also, note that StackExchange is not a forum, it is a collection of Question and Answer sites. If you come from a forum background, you might find this all a little strange, but there are very good reasons we do things the way we do them here. Spend a little time and get to know us; you'll be glad you did.

Comment: OK I will read the FAQ. I like stackexchange, it's really good system. I was visiting similar sites but here is it better, especially the idea that answers from individual users and the whole communication is separated from other users. In other sites I will get lost soon and don't know who is talking with whom.