# Should a suspended account be able to mark a question as a favourite?

Tags: bug, status-completed, account-suspension

Even though I got <s>banned</s> suspended, I'm able to mark a question as a favorite. Is this functionally correct?

Comment: I don't see how marking a question as favorite has anything to do with a ban.

Comment: iam not getting you

Comment: even though you got bannned, you still can able to successfully logged in to the site, is that functionally correct?

Comment: Right, now the question makes sense (kind of).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If by *ban*, you mean that stackoverflow isn't accepting questions/answers from your account, then, why would it be appropriate to prevent you from marking questions as favourites?

The ban is to prevent negative behaviour that detracts from the value of the site, i.e. poor questions/answers. You being able to mark a question as a favourite doesn't, and I'd be hard presssed to see how it could, detract from the value of the site (unless you sit and mark, lets say, all the questions, as favourites).

Comment: And an automated [ban for questions only](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63432/sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account), showing *Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.*, would even still allow one to post answers. But in this case, [the user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/668970/damodar) is not banned, but suspended.

Answer (score 6):

There was a bug in the javascript that made it *seem* like you could favorite questions - the server still rejected any attempts you made.

A fix will be deployed in the next push.

Comment: [Regression](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248549/buggy-error-message-trying-to-use-favorite-from-a-suspended-account)? :/

Comment: Fixed in next build.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for taking a look so quickly!