# Buggy error message trying to use "favorite" from a suspended account

Tags: bug, status-completed, account-suspension, error-message

The problem exists in different browsers (this screenshot was taken from a firefox), and on different sites (or, at least on physics SE, SO and SF).

I think, somewhere in the code internally the bookmarks are used similarly as the votes, and voting is forbidden for suspended accounts. Maybe here is the problem.

The problems happen *exclusively* with suspended account, my normal accounts are working fine.

The screenshot is from [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/165037/transistor-common-base-configuration) (but anywhere happens the same with suspended account).

> [image]

**Extension:** It is solved. Suspended accounts it is impossible to create and even *remove* bookmarks. The popup contains the "Suspended users cannot vote" message.

**Extension #2:** Now the popup contains the "Suspended users cannot favorite questions" message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a regression in the client code; a fix will be pushed out today.

Comment: So suspended account can't favorite questions?

Comment: @ShadowWizard remember that favorites are linked with badges, and therefore are prone to being abused,

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, exactly the same popup happens as if I tried to vote.

Comment: Thank you, it works!

Comment: Hmm... Jarrod can't the message be changed to "suspended users cannot **favorite** questions" instead? Pretty minor, but still..

Comment: @ShadowWizard fine, fine - next build will have your better error message :)  I'm always a bit reluctant to add text for one-offs, due to translation overhead.

Comment: Don't have a suspended account to see it in action, so taking your word for it. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard OH, WE CAN FIX THAT, MUHAHAHA

Comment: *hides in a corner* :D