# Can a suspended user use saves?

Tags: feature-request, support, account-suspension, saves

Is it possible for a suspended user to add new saves? If not, could this be changed?

I would guess that a suspended user is still able to *see* their saves and [search using in:saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=in%3Asaves) - if not, consider this as a part of this feature request, too.

---

Saves evolved from bookmarks - so I assume it works same as for them. I have tagged this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) - since from some older posts it seems that the ability to add new bookmarks wasn't available to suspended users.

- [Buggy error message trying to use "favorite" from a suspended account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248549)
- [Should a suspended account be able to mark a question as a favourite?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86913)
- [Could we allow suspended users to bookmark questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350982)

I am not requesting giving me an opportunity to test this myself. :-)

---

I can certainly imagine somebody, who is temporarily suspended, to still visit a site. And they could think about some question: I could do <this action> if I wasn't suspended. And saves make a great tool to mark such situations if you want to come back later. (Hopefully, the action would be something useful to the site: Posting a nice answer, some copyediting, re-tagging a mistagged question, adding a duplicate that others did not notice etc.)

But even if the saves wouldn't be used for purposes described above - just to mark posts the user wants read later - personally I would be in favor.

Comment: I don't get it. Why give any bonus to someone who broke the rules? Suspended users should have zero privileges, and should not be able to perform any action. That's the whole point of suspension. What you suggest is like giving chef meals to prisoners.

Comment: I get it. Assuming that the better angels of human nature can encourage the *suspendee* to see the value in the network and behaviour can be modified to the benefit of all. (I'm delighted to say, I no longer bite my fingernails, eat worms or wet the bed).

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Still, suspended users are able to do *some* things. (Probably not saves - at least if it works similarly for bookmarks.) So perhaps it's a matter of what you consider appropriate punishment. Moreover, suspensions doesn't necessarily means breaking the rules - many people claim that their suspension was unjust. (Well, this was a bit tongue-in-cheek. I have seen only once a situation where a mod actually suspended a user by mistake - while trying to do something else. In that particular case, suspension was cancelled within 24 hours. Probably such situation are rare.)

Comment: I guess the other question is, would you rather the developers spend time making things nicer for suspended users or spend time making other things nicer for the rest of us?

Comment: Or to put it another way, how much investment in the future of disaffected youth (& other) is the company prepared to make, how much social responsibility will figure into corporate strategy. @RobertLongson

Comment: @RobertLongson That depends on how much work it actually is. (At the moment, it isn't even confirmed whether or not a suspended user can use saves or not - it was just a guess on how it worked for bookmarks. At least some aspects are different for saves - for example, they are private.)

Comment: @RobertLongson on the other hand, I'd rather they spend time making things nicer for the rest of us, than new ways of SMITING THE UNWORTHY

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I Scienced it.

You can save, or unsave a post while suspended. Searching with in:saves works too

As per a comment by a dev - [they're not 'votes' as the old favourites were](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves#comment1276217_382019)  and from my testing with an alternate account everything looks ok.

Answer (score 3):

While I don't know if suspended users can or can't use Saves at this moment, I don't think it would be wise if they could, and that the software shouldn't allow this.

When bookmarks became saves, new badges were also introduced. Which means you would be giving a suspended user some way to "vote" you towards those new badges. Suspended users shouldn't be able to vote. Not only because voting may have gotten them suspended in the first place, but also because you'd want to avoid them doing any damage while they should be cooling off. If you're suspended, you lose your privilege to vote, temporarily.

If they really want to do this, they can keep a tab open or use the bookmark function of their browser. But they are suspended, put in the penalty box, on SE itself, and shouldn't be able to participate until *after* they're out of that again. That includes being able to use the "Saves" feature.

Comment: Do you happen to know about the "support" part of the question? I.e., do you know whether or not it is currently possible for a suspended user to *view* and *search* the saves? (From the wording of your answer it seems that - similarly as bookmarks - saves are technically votes. So that suggests that a suspended user is not *able* to add saves.)

Comment: @Martin most likely they can't Save or remove from Saves, but they can view existing Saves and search them. (Educated guess)

Comment: @Martin no sorry, no data on the support part yet. And you added a disclaimer to your post, soo... ;-) I'll give it a bit of an edit.

Comment: Suspended users can do a lot of things which result in badges. They themselves can work towards the "visited the site on x days" kind badges. They can follow links which will give others badges for sharing links. Why should saves be treated differently?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Just because they can do other things, doesn't mean I agree with them being able to do those other things. For the visited x days badges, I don't think they should lose progress but they definitely also shouldn't gain any progress, that's just an existing flaw of the system. My answer here argues not to add another flaw if/when it turns out suspended users can not use saves. And maybe, one day, to see things changed if it turns out suspended user can use saves (and other functionality they can use while they should be unable to participate from the penalty box)