# Could we allow suspended users to bookmark questions?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, account-suspension

Could we allow suspended users to bookmark questions? I'm aware that [I can't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86913/should-a-suspended-account-be-able-to-mark-a-question-as-a-favourite?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I would like to have this feature changed.

Comment: It would also be nice to enable the `follow` feature for suspended users. Suspended users can click on it and it just silently fails without giving any error messages.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz That would be a separate question.

Answer (score 11):

The technical reason is that bookmarking is casting a vote, and suspended users can't vote. That holds for up- and downvotes, but also voting to delete their own post and bookmarking.

When you're not logged in, you can't bookmark a question either. It's one of the benefits of registering *and* behaving decently.

As an alternative, you can use your browser to bookmark posts. It has better support for it (in the form of categorization) than Stack Exchange anyway.

Comment: On a related note, since following/unfollowing is also technically voting, such as shown in the error message I got & the explaination in the comment to my [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349292/562482), I assume suspended users also won't be able to follow or unfollow any posts. However, if a post they're following has a lot of activity, so they're getting many inbox messages, this could be annoying. Thus, if it's not done so, at least being able to unfollow posts even while suspended could be useful.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I don't think dev time should be spend on optimizing the UX for suspended users. Maybe in 6 to 8 weeks when all the other stuff we asked for is implemented and done.